# maxiterations in Traversal produces error 1909 although no cycles (arangodb)

Tags: arangodb

during a traversal with maxDepth > 2, the system throws error 1909 "too many iterations".

### Example 1 works (with maxiterations:1 maxdepth: 2)

FOR end_vertex IN TRAVERSAL(categories, subcategoryOf,
        "categories/1410476323", "inbound", 
        {strategy: "breadthfirst", order: "postorder", itemOrder: "forward", minDepth: 2, 
        maxiterations: 1, maxDepth: 2, paths: false, 
        uniqueness: {vertices: "global", edges: "global" } } ) 
    RETURN end_vertex.vertex._id

--> it returns about 700 objects.

### Example 2 works NOT (maxdepth: 3, even with maxiterations:1000000)

FOR end_vertex IN TRAVERSAL(categories, subcategoryOf,
        "categories/1410476323", "inbound", 
        {strategy: "breadthfirst", order: "postorder", itemOrder: "forward", minDepth: 2, 
        maxiterations: 1000000, maxDepth: 3, paths: false, 
        uniqueness: {vertices: "global", edges: "global" } } ) 
    RETURN end_vertex.vertex._id

--> normally it should return about 4500 objects.
But it throwhs this error 1909 "too many iterations (while executing)".

I thought due to the uniqueness parameters cycles wouldn't be followed,
so they could not be the cause for iterations, right?

Can anybody give me a hint, what the root cause could be?

Best Regards,
Stefan

P.S.: the graph in total has about 200.000 vertices and 500.000 edges

Answer (score 2):

Hi just out of curiosity have you tried: `maxIterations` as your parameter (note the capital "I")?
`maxiterations` will be ignored by arangodb.
You first query shuld actually not work if there is more than 1 vertex 2 hops away from your start vertex. Using `maxIterations: 1` will only return if there is at most 1 element in the traversal result.

Edit: Right now `maxIterations` and `uniqueness` are handled independently from oneanother.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, mchacki!!!! That was it. 
The typo led me completely into the wrong direction. 
I didn't find any information about the intension of maxIterations and thus, misunderstood the result behaviour completely.

Now with huge values vor maxIterations I get results even for deep traversals!

Thanks again for your help!